# How can I connect a C# SSLStream client to an OpenSSL server?

Tags: c#, openssl, client, ssl-certificate, sslstream

I am currentry writing **a C# client** (with Mono using SSLStream) **for an already existing OpenSSL server** written in C++. I know that in theory, they should be able to communicate, but I always get an Exception:

> Authentication or decryption has failed.

Which takes place in *Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback* when I invoke `sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(ServerName)`;

**I do not need client authentication**, so i don't use any client certificate, and i can't load my server certificate into a client's trust store, as I can't use the command line on the client side.

On the server, I seem to receive some random data, which should not happen, as I never invoke `sslStream.Write()` in the client code. Maybe I don't completely understand how the handshake happens. I have an OpenSSL C++ client that works perfectly though.

Does someone know How I could get this working?

I am using, on the server side, a self-signed certificate generated by OpenSSL, which i converted to DER format.

### How I proceed:

#### Server side

1. Initialize OpenSSL
2. Load server certificate (DER) and private key (PEM)
3. Open a non-SSL listening socket
4. As a client connects, I open a new socket which I connect to an SSL_Bio and accept the connection
5. Read the SSL socket for incoming data.

#### Client side

I am trying to connect using a temporary client adapted from the one in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451910/c-sharp-ssl-secure-sockets).

1. Open a new TCPClient
2. Link a new SSLStream to it with the same validation callback as in the thread above;
3. Calling AuthenticateAsClient(ServerName) which brings this exception.
4. Invoke `sslStream.Write` but the execution never gets here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not sure to understand how sslStream internally works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it. In fact, I was setting up the `BIO` and the `SSL` variables in the wrong order. You have to create and attach your BIO to your SSL **BEFORE** you actually call `SSL_Accept` in OpenSSL, otherwise the authentication cannot complete, which seems logical.

Also, I was using `SSLStream` in C# on client side to send my messages, while I was using `BIO_read` and `BIO_write` on the server Side with OpenSSL.

This could *not* work, because `BIO_read` and `BIO_write` **are no equivalent** to `SSL_read` and `SSL_write`. These two functions only read and write on the underlying socket, without any encryption or decryption, making the SSL handshake almost useless (aside from checking the identity of the other end of the line).

This explains why I was not able to engage communication as the two ends did not speak the same language: one sent unencrypted messages while the other expected SSL-wrapped messages and the other way round.

The `SSL_read` and `SSL_Write` functions take care of the encryption and decryption, so they are the ones to use here. Now it works perfectly.

If you need any further details about how I did that, please comment this answer.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make a SSLStream Server and a OpenSSL Client Connect. When my SSLStream envokes the ReadFunction to read the message sent from the Client, it throws back an IO Exception. I am having a similar speculation of the message language is different but cannot think of any solution to make it uniform across the platform.

Comment: Hi, I do also have a C# SSLStream client and an OpenSSL server c++. The moment it executes sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("ServerCertificateName"); it gives the error. 
Error message: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
InnerException : {"The message received was unexpected or badly formatted"}.
Can you also share code on how you create and attach your BIO to your SSL BEFORE you actually call SSL_Accept in OpenSSL. Thanks.

Comment: Since this is something I did almost 10 years ago, I do not have the source code at hand right now and the code being part of proprietary software I would require adapting it, but I think I could find it again and update the answer when I have access to my back-up